# Using for loop with bs4.element.tag in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning the basics of web-scraping and am using Indeed as my testing ground.

I'm excluding sections of my code that I'm happy with to avoid a lengthy post. The "indeed(dot)com" portion of the print statement will be substituted with "site" so my post does not get  auto-removed or flagged.

the related_jobs variable is of type bs4.element.tag. My code is as follows:

```
for job in jobs:
     related_jobs = job.find('span', class_ = 'mat')
     print(f"All Postings By {company_name}: site{related_jobs}")
```

Here is one of the outputs for the print statement:
[image: print_statement_screencap]

My issue is as follows: I want to append the "site" variable to the first 'a' tag in the span tag and when I try and implement that this way:

```
related_jobs = job.find('span', class_ = 'mat').a['href']
```

, the output is exactly how I want it but does not continue after the first listing. I receive this error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'".

My Question: Is there a way to have my for loop continue throughout the entire listing of the page? If not, is there a string method that I can use to grab the first a tag?

Comment: To avoid breaking your code you could use [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to catch the error and safely keep running the loop.

Comment: @pazitos10 I don't know how to award you the answer but the try/except error catching method fixed the entire problem. If you'd like to comment that officially so I can do so, i'd love to give you the answer! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad you could solve it but unfortunately you cannot award a comment and apparently another user has created the answer so no problem, go award her/him. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some iterations in your loop find no `jobs`. What you can do is either use `try/except` statement or do an if check:

```
for job in jobs:
    related_jobs = job.find('span', class_ = 'mat')
    if not related_jobs:
        # no jobs - skip this iteration
        continue
    related_jobs = related_jobs.a['href']
    print(f"All Postings By {company_name}: site{related_jobs}")
```

or more pythonic approach is to use `try/except` statement:

```
for job in jobs:
    try:
        related_jobs = job.find('span', class_ = 'mat').a['href']
    except (AttributeError, KeyError):
        continue
    print(f"All Postings By {company_name}: site{related_jobs}")
```